# R: Legendas sobrepostas [ggplot2]

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá,
pessoal,estou com um problema de sobreposição de legendas no ggplot. Aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro.

```
Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which
will replace the existing scale.
```

Eu utilizei dois data.frames sobrepostos cujas estruturas seguem:

```
dput(newdf)
structure(list(Col2 = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L
), T_Ef = c("Col22", "Col22", "Col22", "Col22", "Col22", "Col22", 
"Col22", "Col22", "Col22", "Col23", "Col23", "Col23", "Col23", 
"Col23", "Col23", "Col23", "Col23", "Col23", "Col23", "Col26", 
"Col26", "Col26", "Col26", "Col26", "Col27", "Col27", "Col27", 
"Col27", "Col28", "Col28", "Col23", "Col23", "Col24", "Col24", 
"Col26", "Col26", "Col26", "Col27", "Col22", "Col23", "Col24", 
"Col22", "Col22", "Col22", "Col22", "Col22", "Col23", "Col23", 
"Col23", "Col24", "Col25", "Col26", "Col26", "Col27", "Col27", 
"Col27", "Col27", "Col27", "Col28", "Col28"), Exist_ = c("Sim", 
"Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", 
"Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", 
"Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", 
"Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", 
"Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", 
"Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", 
"Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim"), contar = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), total = 1:60), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), .Names = c("Col2", "T_Ef", "Exist_", "contar", "total"
))
```

e

```
dput(newdf2)
structure(list(Col2 = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L
), T_IP = c("Col11", "Col11", "Col12", "Col12", "Col13", "Col13", 
"Col13", "Col14", "Col15", "Col15", "Col15", "Col12", "Col12", 
"Col12", "Col11", "Col11", "Col11", "Col11", "Col12", "Col12", 
"Col13", "Col14", "Col14", "Col15"), Ex_IP = c("Sim", "Sim", 
"Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", 
"Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim", 
"Sim", "Sim", "Sim", "Sim"), Qt = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), total_2 = 1:24), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), .Names = c("Col2", "T_IP", "Ex_IP", "Qt", "total_2"))
```

Os labels que criei são os seguintes:

```
dput(Label_ef)
c("Ef1", "Ef2", "Ef3", "Ef4", "Ef5", "Ef6", "Ef7")

dput(IPs) 
c("OP", "Conselhos", "Conferências", "Mov. Sociais", "Outros")
```

A pergunta seria: como eu poderia consertar a sobreposição de legendas?

Seguem os códigos que utilizei e a imagem gerada. Grato!

```
dt_plot = ggplot() +
  geom_jitter(data= newdf, aes(x=Col2, y=total, fill=T_Ef),
            shape=21, size=4, alpha=0.2) +
            scale_fill_discrete(labels= Label_ef) +
  geom_jitter(data=newdf2, aes(x=Col2, y=total_2, fill=T_IP),
          shape=24, size=3, alpha=0.5) + 
          scale_fill_discrete(labels=IPs) +
          theme_classic()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Infelizmente, a tua pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R, de modo que as pessoas que querem te ajudar consigam fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: ok. vou tentar criar um exemplo reproduzível. como sou 'novato' nesse no ambiente R, ainda tenho um pouco de dificuldades para isso, mas vou tentar e posto aqui. valeu!

Comment: Não é [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905056/multiple-legends-with-ggplot2) que quer?

Comment: Você pode usar o comando `dput()` nos seus dados e postar na pergunta, assim conseguimos trabalhar com a mesma base de dados que você.

Comment: Rui Barradas, obrigado pela dica, é mais ou menos o que quero sim, embora ainda não tenha conseguido aplicar para o meu caso aqui. continuarei tentando seguindo essas pistas aí. valeus!

Comment: Vou tentar fazer isso, Flávio. Super valeu pela dica!

Answer (score 4):

O warning que tu recebe ao fazer este gráfico já diz o que está ocorrendo:

```
Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which
will replace the existing scale.
```

Ou seja, adicionar outra escala de fill vai fazer a segunda escala sobrepor a primeira. Até onde sei, não dá pra resolver este problema. É uma característica do `ggplot2`. O que te sugiro é substituir uma das escalas com fill por colour. Veja como fiz isto e, em seguida, o resultado que obtive:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_jitter(data= newdf, aes(x=Col2, y=total, fill=T_Ef),
              shape=21, size=4, alpha=0.2) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="T_Ef", labels=Label_ef) +
  geom_jitter(data=newdf2, aes(x=Col2, y=total_2, colour=T_IP),
              shape=24, size=3, alpha=0.5) + 
  scale_colour_discrete(name="T_IP", labels=IPs) +
  labs(x="Ano", y="Total") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os T_IP ficaram com fundo branco, mas tem as bordas coloridas. Até onde sei, desconfio que não haja uma maneira de fazer estas escalas de cores em que ambas sejam definidas através de fill. Talvez dê pra fazer algo utilizando scale manual, mas isto está além do meu conhecimento.

Comment: Esta já é uma boa solução, Marcus. Grato por ela e pela explicação. Ademais, verifiquei que agora sim consegui fazer uma questão reproduzível. Super valeu pela interação!

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.